# Non-expiring download link through Dropbox Chooser

Tags: php, api, plugins, download, dropbox

The Dropbox Chooser returns 2 link types: preview and direct. By appending ?dl=1 at the end of the direct download link you can force Dropbox to send the file to the user's browser.

Now that's great and exactly what I want only that the direct link expires after a couple of hours.

Is there any way to get a permanent direct download link to a dropbox file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 'direct' link type returned by the Chooser actually returns a link that references the file directly by default, even without ?dl=1, but it does expire after four hours.

The ?dl=1 modification actually makes Dropbox tell the browser to download the file.

In any case, you can also modify the 'preview' links, which don't expire, to get either of these behaviors as well, as documented here:

https://www.dropbox.com/help/201/en

In short, using the dl subdomain (instead of www) makes it behave like a direct link, and appending ?dl=1 makes it download.

Comment: Yes, thanks! I forgot to test that out but that works. Like you said, just replace www with dl on the preview link and append ?dl=1 and I've got what I need :)

Comment: do dropbox links automatically expire by default?

Comment: This is documented on the Chooser page: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/dropins/chooser/js In short, "preview" links (or modified preview links, as above) don't expire, but can be revoked by the user manually. "Direct" links expire after four hours.